# How do I find this coordinate given the angle and distance from origin

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Here is my problem, I know that if when the coordinates and angles are polar I can use:

**x1 = d*Cos(45) + x0**

**y1 = d*Sin(45) + y0**

But what if my coordinate system works like this? Up/North positive on the Y axis is always zero degrees with 90 degrees being positive on the x axis, all angles are taken clockwise relative from zero (up/north)

Answer (score 1):

Your coordinate system zero angle differs by Pi/2 and goes in another direction.
So

```
Fi = Pi/2 - Alpha
```

Where Alpha is angle in usual coordinate system, Fi - in your system.

```
x1 = d*Cos(Pi/2 - Alpha) + x0 = d*Sin(Fi) + x0
y1 = d*Sin(Pi/2 - Alpha) + y0 = d*Cos(Fi) + y0
```